# Loop and concatenate 2 cell value between specific range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to identify a specific range in column-A and concatenate two cells within the specific range and delete the empty cell. I have been successful in putting a code together and it does the job very well. But, I don't know how to **loop** it to identify next range. Any help would be appreciated.

As per below image and code, First, I am finding and selecting a range between two (MCS) in column-A with a condition that, if the rows are more than 8 between two MCS. Then I am concatenating first 2 cells immediately after MCS and delete the empty row.

The below code works well for first range but I am unable to loop to identify next range from row 22 to 32 and perform concatenations. I want to loop in column-A as there will be more MCS.

[image]

```
Sub MergeStem()
    Dim findMCS1 As Long
    Dim findMCS2 As Long
    Dim myCount As Integer
    Dim myStems As Long
    Dim mySelect As Range
    Dim c As Range

    findMCS1 = Range("A:A").Find("MCS", Range("A1")).Row
    findMCS2 = Range("A:A").Find("MCS", Range("A" & findMCS1)).Row

    myCount = Range("A" & findMCS1 + 1 & ":A" & findMCS2 - 1).Cells.Count
    Range("B1").Value = myCount
    MsgBox "Number of rows =" & myCount

    Set mySelect = Selection

    If myCount > 8 Then
        myStems = Range("A" & findMCS1 + 2 & ":A" & findMCS2 - 9).Select

        Set mySelect = Selection

        For Each c In mySelect.Cells
            If firstcell = "" Then firstcell = c.Address(bRow, bCol)
            sArgs = sArgs + c.Text + " "

            c.Value = ""
        Next
        Range(firstcell).Value = sArgs
    End If

    Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You only do the Find once, so you need to build in a loop. There are many examples online - looks like you should be able to have a go.

Comment: I am not a programmer but i tried the help of stackoverflow to assemble some code. But unable to loop. Any help would be wonderful. Thanks

Comment: Why do you leave out rows 13-22?

Comment: The row count between 13 and  22 is 8, so only if it is more than 8 I need to find and select that range.

Comment: So the number of rows in between needs to be more than 8. I'll take a look later today if it hasn't already been answered.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ?? You've accepted an answer?

Comment: Initially the answer seems to work for small data, but later when I tested extensively today it is not working as expected.I forgot to reject. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim i As Long, Lastrow As Long, Startpoint As Long, Endpoint As Long, Diff As Long
    Dim str As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        Startpoint = 0
        Endpoint = 0

        For i = Lastrow To 2 Step -1

            str = .Range("A" & i).Value

            If str = "MCS" And Startpoint = 0 Then
                Startpoint = i
            ElseIf str = "MCS" And Startpoint <> 0 Then
                Endpoint = i
            End If

            If Startpoint > 0 And Endpoint > 0 Then

                Diff = Startpoint - Endpoint

                If Diff > 8 Then

                    .Range("A" & Endpoint + 1).Value = .Range("A" & Endpoint + 1).Value & " " & .Range("A" & Endpoint + 2).Value
                    .Rows(Endpoint + 2).EntireRow.Delete

                    Startpoint = 0
                    Endpoint = 0

                End If

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Error 1104, I am surprised that your seems to worked initially, but now it is picking  the ranges randomly. Not all range between MCS with more than 8 rows are picked. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Siraj sorry to hear that. please debug the code using break points & immediate window, and check carefully what values each variable get and try to investigate the problem. As soon as you arrived in a conclusion and manage to find something let me know in order to help you.